# Create variables with the callback sheerock js

Tags: javascript, jquery, sheetrock

I have my data on Google Spreadsheets and I used Sheetrock.js and jquery for make queries. It's great. But, i really want save the data in variables by Javascript. For example, i received the name of full name of the person that i searched and i want save his name in a specific variable for using in Leaflet, later. Save the cells[A] o something like that.

I think works with callback but i don't know how to uses.
Thats my javascript

```
var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PY42LQfn1ad5VkzSuyw1mRsAqRyI6yX_lUVPYGbUw4A/edit#gid=0';
var button2 = $('#btn2'), elem = $('#textbox_id');

button2.on('click', function(e){ 
  var v =  elem.val();
  $('#switch-hitters').sheetrock({
      url: mySpreadsheet,
      query: "select A,B,C,D,E where A like '" + v + "%'",
  });
})
```

If you want test you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/ijaguirre/s4ha1stv/1/ 
for example try with 'CLAUDIA'

Answer (score 0):

```
button2.on('click', function(e){ 
  var v =  elem.val();
  sheetrock({
      url: mySpreadsheet,
      query: "select A,B,C,D,E where A like '" + v + "%'",
      callback: function (error, options, response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
  });
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s4ha1stv/5/

You can then work on the error or response: modify each rows and then create your own html table or use if somewhere else in Leaflet if you want.

Comment: How to use this callback to save a variable. For example, if the information has 4 columns and I want to save every one separately. I want somethink like var name = Cells.array [0] or something like this. I need use this data later, but like new variable. I don't know how use this callback

Comment: the response from callback contain all the rows fetched from your spreadsheet. So instead of using the default table created by sheetrock, you can modify each rows and then create your own html table. I have updated my answer. Hope its easy to understand.